# Можно ли написать телеграмм бота сразу на двух библиотеках? (Python)

Tags: python, telebot, pyrogram

Можно ли написать телеграмм бота сразу на двух библиотеках?
Например на pyrogram и pytelegrambotapi.
Суть заключается в том, что pyrogram, может делать то, что не может pytelegrambotapi. При соединение этих двух библиотек выдаёт ошибку:
`RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread2'`
Я почти на сто процентов уверен, что никак нельзя их совместить, но решил узнать мнение профессионалов.

Comment: Вопрос: а зачем?

Comment: Я вроде написал. Pyrogram, может делать то, что не может pytelegrambotapi.
Поэтому хотелось их совместить

Comment: Может тогда тока pyrogram ?

Comment: Как раз таки в этом и проблема.
Не могу я только на одном из них писать, оба нужны(

Comment: Кстати, возможно нашел ответ. В bot.polling(), дописать threading=False

Comment: а что такого может делать pyrogram, чего нет в pytelegrambotapi?